# WP8.1/WinRT User Control Binding from Bound Dependency Property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a User Control that is passing multiple properties to an internal textblock, like so:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root">

     <Grid>
         <TextBlock x:Name="ContentBlock" 
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                    FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily}"
                    FontWeight="{Binding FontWeight}"
                    Text="{Binding Text}"
                    LineHeight="{Binding LineHeight}"
                    Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"
                    />
     </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

And in the user control I have the following:

```
public CustomTextBlock()            
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
        typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBlock), null);
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValueDp(TextProperty, value); }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
{
    SetValue(property, value);
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Where I'm using this control I'm binding to a few of those properties like so:

```
<controls:CustomTextBlock Text="{Binding Question.Text}"
                            FontSize="30"
                            MaxHeight="130"
                            Margin="0, 0, 10, 0"/>
```

However, the text isn't being passed through the binding into the control properly. Everything I've seen says this should work, but it's not. Any ideas what's causing my text not to be passed through to the dependency property?

Comment: Looks right to me ... do you see any binding errors in the Output window?

Comment: No binding errors that I can see, no.

Answer (score 0):

Your control is of type `CustomTextBlock` yet the property is defined as owned by `typeof(ShrinkingTextBlock)`. These need to match for the binding to work.

Comment: Sorry, missed when anonimizing the code. They do match in the actual code (edited to fix)

Comment: It's possible that changing the DataContext while the control isn't yet loaded, but when the controls are already created doesn't raise an update to the bindings.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `SetValueDp` with just `SetValue` and remove `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation? Controls shouldn't really implement that.

Comment: No. I added the SetValueDp when a straight SetValue didn't work.

Comment: I'd just add a change handler to the `Text` property and update the `Text` of your `TextBlock` manually. It will save you some cycles actually.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it does make for a nasty OnPropertyUpdated method (I actually have several properties that are forwarded over to the TextBlock)

Comment: Well, manual plumbing is making a comeback these days when bindings seem too heavy.